# git push heroku master issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm using `git push heroku master`, I'm facing the issue as shown in the below figure:

[image]

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: you are using ruby 2.3.1, you need to update to at least 2.5

Answer (score 1):

With your log error, your ruby is not supported by Heroku. Check Heroku document then upgrade your Ruby version [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the heroku error logs, your ruby version is not upto date.

In your Gemfile, add this line to the top.

```
ruby '2.5.3'
```

run `bundle install`, commit and push again to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good practice to specify your ruby version for all your project. This is good when you are moving your project from one environment or different server.

Add `ruby '2.5.3'` in your `Gemfile` as top most line and `bundle`